# Python CSV writer truncates strings

Tags: python, csv, truncate

I have script that writes a list of lists into a CSV file. Works fine except for one problem: a certain column in the data is ALWAYS truncated to 256 chars in the output file.
I checked the data before writing (used "print" command) and it seems that it contains the full length (~600 chars). The weirder thing is that there's another column with typical data ~1000 chars and it is not getting truncated.

*Edit*: Here's a minimal code that reproduces the problem. Note that the second string is much shorter than the third string, but still it is truncated in the csv but the third string is written entirely without truncation.

```
import csv
mylist = [[0.43,
          "+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--0.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ;+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--1.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ;+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--2.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ;+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--3.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ;+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--4.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ;+/Men-s-Casual-British-Style-Canvas-Sports-Shoes--5.jpg::Men's Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes ",
          "<span style='font-size:14px;'><span style=''><strong>Description:</strong></span><br />\n<span style=''>Men&#39;s Casual British Style Canvas Sports Shoes</span><span style=''> are made of high quality material.It&#39;s Very comfortable.It&#39;s your best choice to go to sport.If you take it,The Simple British design will creates an eye-catching visual effect. It is a perfect gift for someone special or treats for you.<br />\n<br />\nMaterial:Canvas<br />\nColor:Black,Yellow,Blue<br />\nOccasion: Sport<br />\n<br />\n<strong>Details&nbsp;in&nbsp;size:</strong></span></span><br />\n<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' height='81' width='500'>\n\t<tbody>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td style='text-align: center;'>\n\t\t\t\t<span style='font-size:14px;'><span style=''>US Size</span></span></td>\n\t\t\t<td style='text-align: center;'>\n\t\t\t\t<span style='font-size:14px;'><span style=''>9</span></span></td>\n\t\t\t<td style='text-align: center;'>\n\t\t\t\t<span style='font-size:14px;'> Text goes on and on and on.</span></span></div>\n"]]
with open("test.csv", mode='wb') as f:
    dataWriter = csv.writer(f)
    dataWriter.writerows(mylist)
```

Did anyone encounter this? Any hint would be of assistance. I use Python 2.7 (Anaconda distribution)

Thanks.

Comment: It may help to post some code where your problem is occuring.

Comment: is it binary data that might have a "\r" or a "\x00"

Comment: How are you viewing the cvs file?  In a text editor?  In Excel?

Comment: Are you using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to write the file? If so, [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=writer#csv.writer) objects operate under a set of formatting rules collectively known as a [`dialect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=dialects#csv-fmt-params). These control things like whether quote characters surround fields and the handling of certain special characters within fields. It's possible you need to change one these if you can figure-out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Please read [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then provide one illustrating the problem (with data).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. I added a sample code to make it easier for you to respond

Comment: @JoranBeasley - No, it's unicode text.

Comment: @martineau - I read a bit on the dialect rules. I don't understand how this is related, or what I can change to test the behavior. I use the default dialect (excel), and it works fine for one string and fails on the other. I also tried turning on strict=True and got no error on my input

Comment: I mentioned dialect because the contents of the strings could matter (more than their length). However I now think the problem is the fact that the strings in your list are Unicode is the problem. There's a note right in the first part of the [`csv` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) for Python 2.x that says "This version of the csv module _doesn’t support Unicode input_. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe" (italics mine).

Comment: The unicode issue is unrelated. I tried it with plain ASCII and the problem still exists (also edited the question to regular strings). Also as you can see - There are no null characters in the strings. It's all printable ASCII chars (as far as I can tell...). It's driving me nuts. What's the difference between the first and second string? Why is the first truncated and the other isn't??

Comment: OK I found the problem. It's stupid excel, and it's probably because the string starts with a '+' so it thinks it's a formula or something. Opened with a text editor and all is fine